# How to enable shutdown sound on ubuntu 12.04 LTS and up

Tags: 12.04, sound, shutdown

I need a sound to play when I shutdown. In Kubuntu, there's shutdown sound. But Ubuntu, not anymore

Comment: You can install music123 to play .ogg, .wav and mp3 files in place of mpg123.

Comment: you can also install vorbis-tools to play other format's.

Comment: @JOHNNYG Please read http://askubuntu.com/faq if you still want to create an answer for this question.

Answer (score 8):

The "most simple" way would be to automate this process with a small bash script.

First, you need to take care of some dependencies by installing the `mpg123` package, which can play mp3 files from the command line. You should be able to find similar packages for .ogg files as well.

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Next, you have to create the actual script that'll play the shutdown sound: (hint, you can replace `pico` with `gedit` if you don't feel comfortable editing files in the terminal. You can name the file whatever you want, but make sure you keep the K99 part in front of the file name for processing priority reasons.

```
sudo pico /etc/init.d/K99shutdownsound.sh
```

here's the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
## play shutdown sound
/usr/bin/mpg123 /path/to/your/shutdown.mp3
```

make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/K99shutdownsound.sh
```

Now you have to create a link from this script to `/etc/rc0.d` (where shutdown scripts go) and to `/etc/rc6.d` (where reboot scripts go)

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/K99shutdownsound.sh/etc/rc0.d/K99shutdownsound.sh
```

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/K99shutdownsound.sh /etc/rc6.d/K99shutdownsound.sh
```

And now you have a shutdown sound. Just make sure you're not going to play a 5 minute mp3 file, since the system won't halt until it finishes streaming the file.

Comment: I recomend to use package 'music123' as it supports any kind of sound format such as mp3, ogg, wav, etc. etc.

Comment: KXX (XX is number of order) is ordered in asciibetical. using number 99 for the external script will probably fail to sound because the sound has been disabled at certain number of order. Try to experiment by putting the shutdown sound order into first priotity into 'K01shutdownsound.sh' and don't forget to make it executable as well (make sure it has been, double check it). Just leave the current 'K99shutdownsound' script and link intact.

Comment: why did you use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `bash`? and why is the path to `mpg123` needed?

Answer (score 2):

What I used to do is have a file on my desktop called "Startup.sh" that would run a list of programs I like on startup. I discovered that when the last command in the list is playing a sound with mplayer it will do it right before shutdown OR logout. So, you need to download mplayer first:
`sudo apt-get install mplayer2`

Then, make a file called "Startup.sh" on your desktop. The text of the file should read something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer '[PATH TO SOUND FILE.extension]'
```

You just have to click that file every time you log in. You can add other startup programs you want to the script as well.