# Can you add a startup and a shutdown sound ?

Tags: shutdown, startup

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was wondering if there was any way to insert a startup and shutdown sound (ideally using a piece of software). If anybody has any ideas, they would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is already a startup sound. Or you meant a custom one?

Comment: maybe some answers here can help you. http://askubuntu.com/a/138328/163693

Answer (score 1):

You could make that (and other customizations) by replacing the default sound files in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` (broadly in `/usr/share/sounds/*`).

Try to replace (keep a backup if you want to) these files and check:

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-logout.ogg
```

(remember to use the correct extensions and permissions. You have to use elevated privileges to do the operations. Use `sudo` when doing it from terminal or launch Nautilus with `gksu nautilus &` and then make the customizations. Please comment if you need more help with this.)