# Play logout sound when Gnome session ends

Tags: gnome, shutdown, restart, logout, gnome-session

I want to know a way by which I can run a script, which would play a logout sound, just before Gnome session ends.

By *Gnome session ends* I mean when I click **Logout**, **Restart** or **Shutdown**

I am using Gnome 3.18

Comment: Have you looked here -》 http://askubuntu.com/questions/138282/how-to-enable-shutdown-sound-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-and-up

Comment: @DnrDevil after looking at it, it sounds possible answer. BUT I am looking for an answer that is not based on traditional init system, because are being deprecated

Comment: Ahh ok got yea thought it might help :(